# How to define a configmap variables in Kubernetes's PrometheusRule

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to create a PrometheusRule, in expr I am referring the value from configmap. But I get below error.
Error "8:11: group "test-alert", rule 1, "CertificateExpiration": could not parse expression: 1:13: parse error: unexpected character inside braces: '.'" for field "undefined".

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: PrometheusRule
metadata:
  name: certificate-expiration-alert
  namespace: openshift-console
spec:
  groups:
  - name: certificate-expiration-alert
    rules:
    - alert: CertificateExpiration
      expr: ({{ .Values.certificate-expiration.expiration }} - time()) < 5184000
      for: 5m
      labels:
        severity: critical
      annotations:
        summary: "Certificate expiring soon"
        description: Certificate expiring soon
      configMapRef:
        name: certificate-expiration
```

I tried removing the one {} but still same issue

Comment: Are you trying to install using helm?

Comment: The file cannot be applied individually if you want to use Helm features (Chart + value). Try doing a ```helm upgrade YOUR-APP``` again and let us know if it works.

Comment: I am not using helm, I created a configmap with value in that. Trying to access that value in PR expression.